# How do you remove the extra space to the left of a container if setting the margin and padding to 0 doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a navigation bar but can't get rid of the extra space to the left of the logo container. How can I remove this space?

I've tried setting the margin and padding to 0 but neither worked.

Here's an image of what i'm talking about. I added red borders to make it easier to understand where the containers are:

[image: Here's an image of what i'm talking about. I added red borders to make it easier to understand where the containers are]

The output should have the logo all the way to the left of the menu container. There should be no extra space.

```css
.center-container{
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 1rem;
}

menu{
   background-color: cadetblue;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo{
   height: 1.5rem;
   margin-right: 1rem;
}

.logo-container{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <menu class="center-container">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img class="logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/tortoiseshell-optics/resources/images/logo-white.png">
      <span>Tortoiseshell Optics</span>
    </div>
  </menu>
</header>
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. And note, the screen dump doesn't match the code you posted.

Comment: .center-container { padding: 0; }

Answer (score 2):

`<menu>` elements are usually styled like `<ul>` elements by the browser which have a left padding. Remove it and you get rid of the space:

```css
.center-container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

menu {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.logo {
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <menu class="center-container">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img class="logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/tortoiseshell-optics/resources/images/logo-white.png">
      <span>Tortoiseshell Optics</span>
    </div>
  </menu>
</header>
```

Also note that [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu) for `<menu>` is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center-container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}

menu {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <menu class="center-container">

    <div class="logo-container">

      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/tortoiseshell-optics/resources/images/logo-white.png" class=logo>

      <span>Tortoiseshell Optics</span>

    </div>

  </menu>

</header>
```